# How To insert date when you update the password?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

You can view my pict : 
[My relationship picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT6IM.png)

```
        entities = new sampleEntities();
        User usr = (from i in entities.Users
                    join j in entities.Updates
                    on i.ID equals j.ID
                    where i.NAME == name
                    select i).First();

        usr.PASSWORD = textBox2.Text;
        entities.SaveChanges();
```

so, When I update the password, how to make my update time also entered

Comment: How about `usr.[UpdateTimeProperty] = [updatedDateTimevalue]`? I don't know which property you want to update with updated timestamp.

Comment: Did you want to add a new record to the `Update` table to keep a history or just update the `Date of Update`. If the latter why do you have an additional table to store the `Date of Update`?

Comment: @Scrobi There seems to be a one-to-one relation between User and Update table. Doesn't makes sense if this is the complete table structure and not a part of a bigger picture. It can simply be a column instead.

Comment: @Scrobi : I want to save the update time,
When the user updates the password, time will be changed based on datetime.now,
Ex:
A: change password xxx become xYz, auto update table will save time A change password to 11-10-2017 (dd-mm-yyyy)

A: Then tomorrow A change its password from xYz to 123, Automatic update table will save time A change password to 12-10-2017 (dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 2):

You can override saveChanges.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{

    var addedUsers = ChangeTracker.Entries<User>().Where(x => x.State 
                                       == EntityState.Added).ToList();

    addedUsers.ForEach(x => 
    {
        x.Update = new Update{DateOfUpdate = DateTime.Now}
    });

    var modifiedUsers = ChangeTracker.Entries<User>().Where(x => x.State 
                                           == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

    modifiedUsers.ForEach(x => 
    {
        x.Update.DateOfUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    });

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you intend to track these modified dates for multiple tables better to use a base class with these dates and inherit all tables requiring modified date from this class. That way your saveChanges override will be generic and work for all tables inheriting from that base class.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to update the `Date of Update` you can change the select to also bring this data back and then update both the `User` and `Update` tables

```
entities = new sampleEntities();
var data = (from i in entities.Users
                join j in entities.Updates
                on i.ID equals j.ID
                where i.NAME == name
                select new {user = i, update = j).First();

    data.user.PASSWORD = textBox2.Text;
    if (data.update == null) data.update = new Update();

    data.update.DateofUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: When first registration data, I using 
          `User akun = new User();
            akun.NAME = textBox1.Text;
            akun.PASSWORD = textBox2.Text;
            akun.DateCreate = DateTime.Now;

            entities.Users.Add(akun);
            entities.SaveChanges();`
In table users,
ID = 1
Name = Andy
Password = Andy123
DateCreate = 10-11-2017
UpdateId = NULL
RecoveryId = NULL

Table Update
ID = NULL
DateOfUpdate = NULL

Table Recovery
ID = NULL
DateOfRecovery = NULL

Comment: That is because you have to added an entry to the `Update` table. At what point do you want to add an entry to this table when first updated or when the `user` is created / first registered?

Comment: I want that when first update, 
Or you have any suggest ?

Comment: Then you will need to check if `Update` is null and if it is create a new object. You will also have to change the join to a left join